# have had to do something (for sometime)

Tags: perfect-constructions

Is it possible to use "have had to do something" in this sentence?

I have had to give him a call for one week now. But I am lingering.

Comment: The meaning isn't clear. Do you mean "I ought to have given him a call a week ago, but I have been putting it off"?

Comment: yes that's what I mean

Comment: No, you can't use 'have had to' in that sense. You could say "I have had to remind him every day this week" with reference to an obligation that keeps happening, but you can't use it of one that is ongoing.